# CAS 6.2.x MFA Principal Attribute Trigger 'memberOf' Active Directory Not Working

Tags: cas, multi-factor-authentication

I have CAS 6.2.x running in Kubernetes building the image from this [repo](https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template/tree/6.2).  I am passing in the `cas.properties` file via configmap.I have it wired up against Active Directory and am able to login with the Username/Password.  I am now working to enable MFA with the Google Authenticator plugin.  I have this working as well if I force the flow globally with the following:
`cas.authn.mfa.global-provider-id=mfa-gauth`

When I try to use the values described here for [Multifactor Authentication: Principal Attribute Trigger](https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.2.x/configuration/Configuration-Properties.html#multifactor-authentication-principal-attribute-trigger) it doesn't send me to the MFA flow.  These are the settings that I have set:
`cas.authn.ldap[0].principalAttributeList=userPrincipalName,cn,givenName,sAMAccountName,memberOf`
`cas.authn.mfa.global-principal-attribute-name-triggers=memberOf`
`cas.authn.mfa.global-principal-attribute-value-regex=ForceMfa`

When I log in these are the values returned back for `memberOf`:

> memberOf
> [CN=Group2,OU=MyOu,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=local, CN=Group1,OU=MyOu,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=local, CN=ForceMfa,OU=MyOu,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=local]
> Principal

I used Misagh [blog post](https://fawnoos.com/2018/06/10/cas-mfa-google-authenticator/) as a guide.

If I change the trigger and regex to `sAMAccountName` and my username it then works as expected.  Not sure if I need to change the regex format to find the group name or if I just have something else wrong.  It just seems like the regex is not finding a match for some reason as the settings seem to be working for me, just not with `memberOf`.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider switching this to:

```
cas.authn.mfa.global-principal-attribute-value-regex=.*ForceMfa.+
```

Then, [attach/review your logs](https://apereo.github.io/2018/09/05/effective-diagnostics/#thou-shall-log) for org.apereo.cas under either DEBUG/TRACE so you can see what's happening.

Comment: This worked.  I tried a few wildcard values, or I thought I did, but definitely am not a RegEx guru in any shape or form.

Thank you